# How order fields in FastAPI/SwaggerUI

Tags: fastapi, swagger-ui

I have an API with two parts input, a pydantic class and a list of str. List of str could have zero or more items.

```
from typing import List
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from pydantic import  BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    item_x: str
    item_y: str

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/items")
async def read_items(item: Item = Depends(),related_items: List[str]=Query(None)):

    return "something"
```

Note: This is not my actual code. My actual code has several extra fields and inputs.

In swagger UI, related_items appear before item.

[image]

Is there any way to change the order and make swagger UI display fields in different order?
I did some googling and could not find any solution for my scenario. In another forum, people suggested creating a pydantic class and put everything in the class but it doesn't work for me. I prefer to use Query for related_items and have "Add string item" button in swagger UI.

Comment: The swagger UI is just a development tool, not a end user interface. Why is the order relevant?

Comment: It is mostly because of curiosity, but we also have some use cases that some people, might need to use swagger. Anyway, I'm more interested to know about the possibility of the changes rather than the benefit of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like parameters without `Depends` appear in the OpenAPI schema before the parameters with `Depends`.
This code produces the schema what you want:

```
from typing import List
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from pydantic import  BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    item_x: str
    item_y: str

app = FastAPI()


def related_items(related_items: List[str] = Query(None)):
    return related_items


@app.get("/items")
async def read_items(item: Item = Depends(), related_items: List[str]=Depends(related_items)):

    return "something"
```

You can also modify the OpenAPI schema as shown in the documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/extending-openapi/#modify-the-openapi-schema

Comment: I guess this is not the solution you want to get, but maybe it will help you find the right direction.